# Web scraping through API - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to web scrape a web site through python.
URL = "https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/bond/xs0216072230"

With the code below, I am getting no result, it shows this in output :  {}
Code is below :

```
import requests

url = (
    "https://api.boerse-frankfurt.de/v1/data/master_data_bond?isin=XS0216072230"
)

headers = {
    "X-Client-TraceId": "d87b41992f6161c09e875c525c70ffcf",
    "X-Security": "d361b3c92e9c50a248e85a12849f8eee",
    "Client-Date": "2022-08-25T09:07:36.196Z",
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(data)
```

It should print :

{
"isin": "XS0216072230",
"type": {
"originalValue": "25",
"translations": {
"de": "(Industrie-) und Bankschuldverschreibungen",
"en": "Industrial and bank bonds",
},
},
"market": {
"originalValue": "OPEN",
"translations": {"de": "Freiverkehr", "en": "Open Market"},

Any help would be appreciated, I am avoiding Selenium approach for this at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the link you are trying to scrape itself is empty ..

Comment: @mrCopiCat Is it possible to webscrape this website with Python request module
 url : "https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/bond/xs0216072230"

Answer (score 0):

URL must have some data. https://api.boerse-frankfurt.de/v1/data/master_data_bond?isin=XS0216072230  this url is Empty

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```py
import requests

url = (
    "https://api.boerse-frankfurt.de/v1/data/master_data_bond?isin=XS0216072230"
)

header = {
    "authority":"api.boerse-frankfurt.de",
    "method":"GET",
    "path":"/v1/data/master_data_bond?isin=XS0216072230",
    "scheme":"https",
    "accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.6",
    "client-date":"2022-08-26T18:35:26.470Z",
    "origin":"https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de",
    "referer":"https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/",
    "x-client-traceid":"21eb43fb86f0065542ba9a34b7f2fa93",
    "x-security":"14407a81ab4670847d3d55b0d74a3aea",
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()
print(data)
```

[image]

But I think you might need to update `x-client-traceid`,`client-date`, and `x-security` regularly